# get the array objects in the exact index

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, lookup, reduce

I have an array

```
 let items=[5,1,3,4,2]
```

and an object array

```
   let objectItem=[
            {id:"item-1", name: "Total revenue",selected:true, order: 1},
            {id:"item-2", name: "Total tax",selected:true, order: 2},
            {id:"item-3", name: "Sales Report",selected:false, order: 3},
            {id:"item-4", name: "Total parking",selected:false, order: 4},
            {id:"item-5", name: "Sales maximum",selected:false, order: 5},
            {id:"item-6", name: "Amount Collected",selected:true, order: 6},
            {id:"item-7", name: "Total fall",selected:false, order: 7}
        ]
```

i  need to get the array objectItem in the order in which it matches the order  key with the item array element in the exact order.

my resultant array should be like this,

```
objectItem=[
        {id:"item-5", name: "Sales maximum",selected:false, order: 5},
        {id:"item-1", name: "Total revenue",selected:true, order: 1},
        {id:"item-3", name: "Sales Report",selected:false, order: 3},
        {id:"item-4", name: "Total parking",selected:false, order: 4},
        {id:"item-2", name: "Total tax",selected:true, order: 2},
    ]
```

so far i was able to acheieve the object item array in the ascending order of order key after applying

```
const itemArr=objectItem.filter((itm)=>{
    return items.indexOf(itm.order) > -1;
  });
```

is there any work around to obtain the resulting array with the objects with order value as in the exact index of the items array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let items=[5,1,3,4,2]

let objectItem=[
  {id:"item-1", name: "Total revenue",selected:true, order: 1},
  {id:"item-2", name: "Total tax",selected:true, order: 2},
  {id:"item-3", name: "Sales Report",selected:false, order: 3},
  {id:"item-4", name: "Total parking",selected:false, order: 4},
  {id:"item-5", name: "Sales maximum",selected:false, order: 5},
  {id:"item-6", name: "Amount Collected",selected:true, order: 6},
  {id:"item-7", name: "Total fall",selected:false, order: 7}
]

console.log(items.map(i=>objectItem.find(({order:o})=>o===i)))
```

Comment: This is an expensive (almost quadratic) approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object and get the items in wanted order.

```js
const
    items = [5, 1, 3, 4, 2],
    objectItem = [{ id: "item-1", name: "Total revenue", selected: true, order: 1 }, { id: "item-2", name: "Total tax", selected: true, order: 2 }, { id: "item-3", name: "Sales Report", selected: false, order: 3 }, { id: "item-4", name: "Total parking", selected: false, order: 4 }, { id: "item-5", name: "Sales maximum", selected: false, order: 5 }, { id: "item-6", name: "Amount Collected", selected: true, order: 6 }, { id: "item-7", name: "Total fall", selected: false, order: 7 }],
    hash = Object.fromEntries(objectItem.map(o => [o.id, o])),
    result = items.map(i => hash[`item-${i}`]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach which avoids the almost quadratic effort of a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task that for each iteration step depends on a nested also iterating [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) task can be based on two separate (not nested) iteration cycles ...

- a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which creates a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and `order`-key based `item`-lookup.
- the final `map` task which creates a correctly ordered item-list by iterating the item-precedence array/list and obtaining each item by the currently processed `order`-value where the latter is the lookup's key.

```js
const listOfItems = [
  { id: "item-1", name: "Total revenue", selected: true, order: 1 },
  { id: "item-2", name: "Total tax", selected: true, order: 2 },
  { id: "item-3", name: "Sales Report", selected: false, order: 3 },
  { id: "item-4", name: "Total parking", selected: false, order: 4 },
  { id: "item-5", name: "Sales maximum", selected: false, order: 5 },
  { id: "item-6", name: "Amount Collected", selected: true, order: 6 },
  { id: "item-7", name: "Total fall", selected: false, order: 7 },
];
const itemPrecedenceList = [5, 1, 3, 4, 2];

// - one-time iteration in order to create a
//   `Map` and `order`-key based `item`-lookup.
const itemLookup = listOfItems
  .reduce((lookup, item) => {
    lookup.set(item.order, item);
    return lookup;
  }, new Map);

// - one-time iteration in order to
//   create a correctly ordered item-list.
const reorderedItems = itemPrecedenceList
  .map(order => itemLookup.get(order));

console.log({
  reorderedItems,
  itemPrecedenceList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And in case the OP wants to mutate the original items array by [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)ing it [*in place*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), the above implementation changes to ...

- a single `reduce` task again, where this time a `Map` and `order`-key based new precedence-lookup is going to be created.
- the final `sort` task which is less efficient than the one-time iteration before, but does accomplish the array's *in-place sort* followed by the immediate [truncation of all not needed items via the arrays `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length#shortening_an_array).

```js
const listOfItems = [
  { id: "item-6", name: "Amount Collected", selected: true, order: 6 },
  { id: "item-7", name: "Total fall", selected: false, order: 7 },

  { id: "item-1", name: "Total revenue", selected: true, order: 1 },
  { id: "item-2", name: "Total tax", selected: true, order: 2 },
  { id: "item-3", name: "Sales Report", selected: false, order: 3 },
  { id: "item-4", name: "Total parking", selected: false, order: 4 },
  { id: "item-5", name: "Sales maximum", selected: false, order: 5 },

];
const itemPrecedenceList = [5, 1, 3, 4, 2];

// - one-time iteration in order to create a `Map`
//   and `order`-key based new precedence lookup.
const precedenceLookup = itemPrecedenceList
  .reduce((lookup, order, idx) => {
    lookup.set(order, idx);
    return lookup;
  }, new Map);

// - `sort` task which is less efficient than the one-time 
//   iteration but does accomplish the array's in-place sort ...
listOfItems
  .sort((a, b) =>
    (precedenceLookup.get(a.order) ?? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) -
    (precedenceLookup.get(b.order) ?? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
  )
  // ... with the immediate truncation of all not needed items.
  .length = itemPrecedenceList.length;

console.log({
  listOfItems,
  itemPrecedenceList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```